UTF-16LE encoded Desktop.ini generated by java does not works when it contains chinese characters
I am trying to create a desktop.ini file through java to provide an alternative name for Windows11 folder (Just as My Documents looks like).
Here is a simple code example(It can be called directly to run):
@Test
public void createDesktopIni() throws IOException {
    String folderPath = Write a folder path here;
    String iniPath = folderPath + "\\desktop.ini";
    File file = new File(iniPath);
    // delete and recreate if exist
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    file.createNewFile();
    // Write content
    String alternativeName = "Alternative Name";
    //alternativeName = "这是一个中文别名";
    OutputStreamWriter oStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
    oStreamWriter.write("[.ShellClassInfo]\nLocalizedResourceName = " + alternativeName);
    oStreamWriter.flush();
    oStreamWriter.close();
    // Set system attribute
    Files.setAttribute(Paths.get(folderPath), "dos:system", true, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    Files.setAttribute(Paths.get(iniPath), "dos:system", true, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
    Files.setAttribute(Paths.get(iniPath), "dos:hidden", true, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
}

If I set an English alternative name, the desktop.ini can work normally. (By the way, this file can be opened normally through VSCode at this time).
However, if i set a chinese alternative name such as comment:
alternativeName = "这是一个中文别名";
At this time, the desktop.ini file cannot works.
If I open it through VSCode, the following content will be displayed:

But if I choose Open Anyway->Reopen with UTF-16 LE Encoding, and then save the file as UTF-16 LE through VS Code, it works fine again.
Here are some other encodings I tried:

UTF-8 works, but Chinese characters are garbled in Explorer.exe.
GBK works, and it is not garbled. But I prefer to use UTF-16, I see that the desktop.ini in My Documents folder also uses UTF-16 LE.
UTF-16 not works, and the file will be encoded to UTF-16 BE.


Save yourself a lot of typing by calling Files.writeString or Files.write(Path, byte[])

A Desktop.ini file (or really, any INI file on Windows) that contains Unicode characters must begin with a UTF-16 BOM so the Win32 API knows the content is Unicode. but you are not producing a BOM as you are using StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE which is BOM-less.
You can either:

use StandardCharsets.UTF_16 instead, which has a BOM (but may be either UTF-16 LE or BE):
OutputStreamWriter oStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_16);


continue using UTF_16LE and write a BOM manually before anything else:
OutputStreamWriter oStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
oStreamWriter.write(0xFEFF);
...




oStreamWriter.write(0xFEFF); works!
I tried using UTF-16 before, but this makes the file default to UTF-16 BE, the file itself is fine anymore, but i don't  know why Windows does not use it.
Thanks for your answer!

I learned something about BOM. But wiki says If the 16-bit units use little-endian order ("UTF-16LE"), the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence FF FE. So why write 0xFEFF instead of 0xFFFE here?

Because write(int) expects a character number, not bytes. The actual BOM character is U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE which has a numeric value of 0xFEFF. The Writer will encode characters to bytes using the specified encoding, which in this case will encode character 0xFEFF as bytes FF FE for UTF_16LE and as bytes FE FF for UTF_16BE.
